# Scala type signature failing with subclasses

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have the following exception hierarchy defined:

```
/**
  * Base class for all exceptions in this library
  */
trait MyAkkaHttpException {}

/**
  * Thrown when there is a problem persisting data to a datastore
  */
case class PersistenceException(message: String)
  extends Exception(message: String) with MyAkkaHttpException

/**
  * Thrown when validation on an object fails
  * @param errors
  */
case class ValidationException(message: String, errors: List[String])
  extends Exception(message: String) with MyAkkaHttpException
```

And the following code:

```
class ContactFormService(contactFormPersistor: ContactFormPersistor) {

  def handleForm(contactForm: ContactForm): ValidationNel[MyAkkaHttpException, String] = {

    contactForm.validate() match {
      case Success(_) => contactFormPersistor.persist(contactForm)
      case Failure(e) =>
        new ValidationException(message = "Error validating contact form",
          errors = e.toList).failureNel[String]
    }
  }
}
```

- `contactFormPersistor.persist` returns `ValidationNel[PersistenceException, String]`
- `contactForm.validate()` returns `ValidationNel[String, Boolean]`

The problem is `handleForm` won't accept that `PersistenceException` and `ValidationException` are subclasses of `MyAkkaHttpException`. What do I need to do to make it correctly realise that those return types are valid subclasses?

Comment: Use `+`, I believe.

Comment: @Elazar I tried that but it shows as a syntax error. Please can you write an answer?

Comment: try `ValidationNel[+MyAkkaHttpException, String]`

Comment: @Elazar That gives this error: `Error:(17, 87) identifier expected but ',' found.
  def handleForm(contactForm: ContactForm): ValidationNel[+MyAkkaHttpException, String] = {`

Comment: @raphaëλ Does he even need `+T2`? I would think `class ValidationNel[+T1, T2]` would suffice...

Comment: Yes he only needs covariance on the first type param, but it turns out it is a scalaz type (alias)

Comment: I think I might need to swap `ValidationNel` for `\/` which accepts covariant types on both sides...

Comment: The alias is delcared as `ValidationNel[E, +X] = Validation[NonEmptyList[E], X]`, you need covarience on 1st param. Try using `Validation[+T1,T2]`  or `Validation[NonEmptyList[+E], X]` - but there is a reason there is no covar on `E`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `ValidationNel[MyAkkaHttpException, String]` to `Validation[NonEmptyList[MyAkkaHttpException], String]`. As someone pointed out in the comments, it's only the type alias that is not covariant in the first type argument.

```
type ValidationNel[E, +X] = Validation[NonEmptyList[E], X]
```

Otherwise, `NonEmptyList` and `Validation` are both covariant in all their arguments.

## EDIT:

This might depend on your version of `scalaz`. As far as the latest available that I can browse, it looks like `ValidationNel` [*is* no longer covariant in both arguments](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L209), but [it previously was](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.0.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L205). There is probably a good reason for this change: be prepared to not be able to use Scalaz's functions for `ValidationNel`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you need covariance on the first type parameter of `ValidationNel` and this particular shortcut of `Validation` was not designed with this covariance in mind*

Based on the information i gathered from our comment exchange,  i believe this is the correct way forward. Declare your own alias (or use the type directly)

```
type MyValidationNel[+E, +X] = Validation[NonEmptyList[E], X]
```

*) I do however have a feeling there was a reason behind not having covariance on the `E` param (as scalaz normally is know to do things with a reason)

Answer (score 0):

`Either` is covariant over both the left and right, so I've just switched to that instead.